# Displaying USGS DEM as 3D in ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, 3d-analyst, arcscene, usgs

So I am having some issues getting my USGS DEM to display in 3d in ArcScene. I downloaded my DEM (.jpg) and brought it into ArcScene. I clicked properties and base heights and floating on a custom surface, and then after accepting, the DEM is still completely flat.

What am I doing wrong?

I thought I had already put it into a projected coordinate system.

What coordinate system is it in when I download it from USGS?

How would I change it correctly?

What I am trying to do ultimately is use the 3d elevations for a flood simulation.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: A .jpg is not a DEM.  You likely have a rendered image without elevation. Can you edit your question and specify *exactly* what you downloaded.

Comment: It's rare for a DEM to be stored in a lossy 8-bit format. Usually they are single-band 16-bit rasters with lossless compression (LZ77, etc). Please [edit] the question to provide a great more detail about the raster in question.

Answer (score 1):

A few possibilities I can think of:

First, maybe it's already in 3D, and you just need to view it from a different angle/perspective by e.g. using the mouse to rotate the scene.

Second, maybe the variation in elevation is too small as compared to the extent of your DEM. You may want to try change the [vertical exaggeration](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/how-to-change-the-vertical-exaggeration-for-a-3d-document-in-arcscene.htm) or z-factor.